# List files and subfolders from database in PHP

Tags: php

Beginner : I cant seem to get my head around the logic of it. Have searched but seems to come up with listing files and folders from an actual directory ie. (opendir).

My problem is :

Im trying to work out (in PHP) how to list files and subfolders from a path stored in a database. (Without any access to the file or dir, so just from the path name)

For example database shows:

```
main/home/television.jpg
main/home/sofa.jpg
main/home/bedroom/bed.jpg
main/home/bedroom/lamp.jpg
```

So if i specify `main/home` - it shows: `television.jpg`, `sofa.jpg` and the name of the subfolder : `bedroom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanFolder('main/home');

function scanFolder($dir) {

    foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {

        if (!in_array($file, array('.', '..'))) {

            if (is_dir($file)) {

                scanFolder($dir . '/' . $file);
            }
            else {

                echo $dir . '/' . $file . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand, it's a single path stored in the database, in this case `main/home`.  This is really only a PHP question I think.

Comment: does this ...if (is_dir($file)) {scanFolder($dir . '/' . $file);} display the files inside the path, or just the subfolder name?

Comment: If it's a sub folder it scans it for files. Have you tried it?

Comment: yea, but scandir, reads a directory.. need to display without accessing the file.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to check on each iteration if the filename is a directory or not.  If it is, open it up and read its contents and output them.  A recursive function would work best in this situation.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php